"Authorization" header sent from axios instance not recieved at express middleware
so I made 2 GET requests using an axios instance

const backRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8090/api/",
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default backRequest;

however only this one with '/user' receives a response successfully
sessionStorage.setItem("authToken", token);
backRequest.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
console.log("Header Token:", backRequest.defaults.headers.common);
try {
  const result = await backRequest.get("/user");
  setFirstName(result.data.firstName);
  console.log(firstName);
} catch(error) {
  console.error("Layout error:", error);
}

But the other one doesn't which requests from '/account'
try {
  console.log("fetchAccountData called!");
  console.log("SidePane Token:", backRequest.defaults.headers.common);
  const result = await backRequest.get("/account");
  setBalance_details(result.data);
  console.log('Account linked:', fullName);
  if (fullName) {
    setIsLinked(true);
  } else {
    setIsLinked(false);
    console.log("Data not retrieved!")
  }
} catch(error) {
  console.error("Layout error:", error);
}

Even though the Authorization header was set in the snippet that requests to /user, the header could still be accessed from the snippet in the request to /account from the log.
They both pass through the same middleware but the 'Authorization' header for /account seemed to be lost
export default function authRoute(req, res, next) {
  const idToken = req.headers['authorization'];
  console.log("Entered first middleware!", req.headers);
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  if (idToken) {
    auth.verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then((decodedToken) => {
      if (decodedToken) {
        req['uid'] = decodedToken.uid;
        console.log("Authed User ID", req['uid']);
        console.log("Proceeding to next middleware...")
          next();
      } else {
        console.log("User not authenticated");
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error Token:", error);
      // Handle error
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Got no idToken!:", idToken);
  }
}

const app = express();
const api = Router();

app.use(json())
api.use(authRoute);
api.get('/account', getAccount);
api.get('/user', getUser);

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000", // replace with your frontend's origin
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"],
  exposedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"]
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use('/api', api);
app.listen(8090, () => {
  console.log("Server running on localhost:8090");
});

I tried reordering th middleware additions and even changing token to \Bearer ${token}``, which only seemed to make it worse

When you change backRequest.defaults, that change applies to all future requests made with backRequest, doesn't it?
